# How do I create a pop-up when one cell is clicked based on the contents of another cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell that looks up a table on another worksheet.  Can I popup a message with text from that table when the cell is selected?

For example, `Cell D2` is a drop down menu reading data from `sheet2/Column 'A'` which has choices 1, 2, and 3.  If the user chooses 1, I would like a pop-up message explaining what that choice is. `sheet2/Column 'B'` has the description for the items in Column 'A'.  If they choose 2, then the explanation from column B will popup.

Comment: MsgBox is what you are looking for http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/msgbox.html

Comment: Does it have to be a popup?  I generally find them annoying and would prefer the cell next to the menu to just display the description.  This is also how I have seen this done before and works well.

Comment: ok what would be the best way rather than this long if statement

Comment: use a vlookup based on what they choose in the dropdown to populate either a msgbox or another cell.

Comment: Clarify question title.

Answer (score 0):

E2 would be a sensible place, try there:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D2),"",VLOOKUP(D2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$3,2,0))
```